# Make alternating CSS table row style work in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, row, css-tables

I use this CSS code to display a database output in rows where the colors repeat in every 2nd row

```
tbody tr:nth-child(2n) td, tbody tr.even td {  
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E5ECF9;  
}
```

If I open it in my IE it won't work. Any advice?

I am using IE 8.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

IE8 does not support the `:nth-child` CSS property. You can make it work in IE8 with this script:

https://github.com/roylory/ie7-js

**How to use it:**

You can Include it via conditional comments, e.g.:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<script src="IE9.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

The script will only load in IE9 and below, other browsers do not see it.

***Live demo:*** https://jsbin.com/koyahe/edit?html,css,output

(This demo should work in all versions of IE.)

Comment: This project looks dead. Any more recent references?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Which versions of IE do you need to support? A lot has changed in 5 years.

Comment: MSIE 8, unfortunately. I haven't actually tried this yet, but I assume that MSIE 8 hasn't changed at all, and that `:nth-child` is still a no-go, so I was looking for a fall-back solution. My product already does this "manually" (by having an alternating CSS class used for each table row) but I'm looking to remove useless cruft and if there's a semi-elegant way to do this, I'm interested.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz As long as you can find the ie7-js library somewhere, it should still work as advertised. Not sure where it’s officially located these days.

Comment: Right. I was looking for a reference to the current official location.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I’ve found a repo that hosts a copy of this library, and updated the demo; seems to work in older versions of IE (I’ve tested in IE11 using the emulation modes.)

Answer (score 8):

I like the answer above, but alternate row colours doesn't seem to work if a document isn't refreshed.

Try jQuery too:

```
$("tbody tr:even td").css("background-color", "lightgray");
```

Link:
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Zebra_Striping_Made_Easy

Answer (score 3):

Which version of IE are you using? the `:nth-child()` CSS won't work in old versions of IE.

[IE6, IE7, IE8 Fail](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t38)

IE9 (works)

Comment: is there a way to display it in IE8?

Comment: If you use @Šime Vidas' suggestion of IE7.js it will work in IE8.