# add alternate background style to odd rows of HTML table

Tags: c#, html, css, datatable, html-table

I am creating an email log to report on activities of my application.

The table is working finr but when hundreds of records are output it is difficult to read.

Here is my existing code (I loop through a c# datatable to get the records)

```
foreach (task_creditcases item in creditCases)
{
    sb.Append("<tr>");
    // Document Name
    sb.Append("<td>" + item.c_Id + "</td>");
    sb.Append("<td>" + item.c_Name + "</td>");
    sb.Append("<td>" + "Credit Case" + "</td>");
    sb.Append("<td>" + "Credit Case" + "</td>");
    sb.Append("<td>" + item.c_EquationCustomerNumber + "</td>");
    sb.Append("<td>" + item.c_AdditionalInfo + "</td>");
    sb.Append("<td>" +  Convert.ToDateTime(item.c_Close_Date__c).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "</td>");
    sb.Append("<td>" + item.c_ImagingDocument + "</td>");
    sb.Append("<td>" + item.c_ContentType + "</td>");
    sb.Append("<td>" + item.c_Status__c + "</td>");
    sb.Append("<td>" + item.c_Document_Type__c + "</td>");
    sb.Append("<td>" + item.c_ImagingDSXDirectory + "</td>");
    sb.Append("<td>" + item.c_ImagingDocument + "</td>");
    sb.Append("</tr>");
}

sb.Append("</tbody>");
sb.Append("</table>");
```

how could I add a background shading to every other row?

thanks
Philip

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp, but it does not work in ie8.

Comment: @VladimirFrolov You could use the `nth-child` selector post `foreach` to achieve the same thing? Works then for IE8-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### *Cross Browser solutions*

### Option 1: jQuery

If you're not intending to support IE8 or less then the `nth-child` selector will not work for you. However, using jQuery you can simply add the following as jQuery does support `nth-child`. Or alternatively, in jQuery you can use `:even` and `:odd`. You'd need to figure out when to call this though.

```
$("tbody > tr:even" ).css("background-color", "blue");
$("tbody > tr:odd" ).css("background-color", "red");
```

### Option 2: no jQuery

Or from your code have:

```
var count = 0;
foreach (task_creditcases item in creditCases)
{
    if (count++ % 2 == 0)
        sb.Append("<tr class=\"even\">");
    else
        sb.Append("<tr class=\"odd\">");

    // Rest of sb.code
}
```

Then in your `CSS` file add:

```
tbody > tr.odd { background-color: red; }
tbody > tr.even { background-color: blue; }
```

I'd recommend the second option since you wouldn't have to touch jQuery which applies the styles inline. Performance is better if the styles are in the CSS vs inline.

Comment: `"However, since you are already using jQuery you can simply add the following after your foreach"` - The question makes no mention of using jQuery.  The code in the question is C#, so adding JavaScript code (with or without jQuery) in the same loop won't work.

Answer (score 7):

```
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
   background-color: #bada55;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: lightblue;
}
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/aqKbj)

Comment: this one is better than 1ntello's answer cause it mentions the tbody, excluding the thead row, which generally shouldn't be considered in this case.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that IE8- doesn't recognise the `nth-child` selector.

Comment: For IE8 suppport (via JQ) see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105275/css3-on-ie8-odd-even-row-by-different-color

Answer (score 3):

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}

or

tr:nth-child(even) {background: #FFF}
```

Add one of those to your css, depending on even or oneven rows.

Comment: @Steve: It's not mentioned in this answer, either.

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone,

here is what I did before I saw [jumpingcode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/849843/jumpingcode)'s answer:

```
    foreach (task_cases item in cases)
            {
                //sb.Append("<tr>");
                var idx = 0;

                bool even = idx % 2 == 0;
                if (even)
                    {
                    sb.Append("<tr background-color:#eee;>");
                    }
                else
                    {
                    sb.Append("<tr background-color:#fff;>");
                    }
```