# How do I alternate column background colours in a table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This sounds pretty simple, but I cant find many posts about it.

Basically I want the first column red, 2nd green, 3rd red etc...

How can I do this in css?

Here is my html code (I am using bootstrap 3):

```
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Welsh</th>
                    <th>English</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Shwmae <a href="#" onclick="playAudio('shwmae');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up play"></span></a></td>
                    <td>Hello</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bore da <a href="#" onclick="playAudio('boreda');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up play"></span></a></td>
                    <td>Good morning</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I have tried using the following CSS, but it didn't do anything:

```
col:first-child {background: #FF0}
col:nth-child(2n+3) {background: #CCC}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TG8cd/ ?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430005/add-alternate-background-style-to-odd-rows-of-html-table/19430053#19430053

Comment: Be aware that, currently, none of the answers will work in older browsers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would need to indicate that **columns** exist by adding a colgroup

HTML

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th>Descrizione</th>
    <th>Convenzione</th>
    <th>Privato</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Tomografia computerizzata delle arcate dentarie</td>
    <td>€ 36,15</td>
    <td>€ 100,00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Tomografia computerizzata delle arcate dentarie</td>
    <td>€ 36,15</td>
    <td>€ 100,00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Tomografia computerizzata delle arcate dentarie</td>
    <td>€ 36,15</td>
    <td>€ 100,00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Tomografia computerizzata delle arcate dentarie</td>
    <td>€ 36,15</td>
    <td>€ 100,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tomografia computerizzata delle arcate dentarie</td>
    <td>€ 36,15</td>
    <td>€ 100,00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Tomografia computerizzata delle arcate dentarie</td>
    <td>€ 36,15</td>
    <td>€ 100,00</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

CSS

```
col:nth-child(odd) {
  background:red;
}

col:nth-child(even) {
  background:green;
}
```

[**CODEPEN DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/otflH)

Answer (score -1):

You would use [`tr:nth-child`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild). [Mozilla Docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child)

Example:

```
tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
  ⋮ declarations
}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  ⋮ declarations
}
```

Comment: Columns, not rows.