# Simple CSS: Formatting multiple tables

Tags: css, html-table

I have a rather simple CSS question.

I want to create a table that follows certain formatting. I want to format several tables differently on the same page.

I have this:

CSS:

```
table.firstTable
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
td.firstTable
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
th.firstTable
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #00003f;
    font-color: #cfffff;
}
table.secondTable
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
td.secondTable
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
th.secondTable
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #cfffff;
    font-color: #00003f;
}
```

The only way I can then create tables this way is something like:

HTML:

```
<table class="firstTable">
  <tr>
    <th class="firstTable">Item</th>
    <th class="firstTable">Quantity</th>
    <th class="firstTable">Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="firstTable">0-001</td>
    <td class="firstTable">Computer</td>
    <td class="firstTable">$299.99</td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>

<table class="secondTable">
  <tr>
    <th class="secondTable">Customer ID</th>
    <th class="secondTable">Total Sales</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="secondTable">10001</td>
    <td class="secondTable">$39.94</td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

I *know* there's a better way to accomplish this than constantly repeating the "firstTable" and "secondTable" classes.

I tried doing things with  like this:

CSS:

```
#firstTable table
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#firstTable th
...
```

and then

HTML:

```
<div id="firstTable">
<table>
...
</table>
</div>
```

but it didn't work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

You should look more in to [selectors](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/) (this is pretty basic CSS).

You can select an element inside a element with a class using `element.withClass element`. That way you don't need to give all the `td` and `th` a class, but only the parent element, the `table` in this case:

HTML:

```
<table class="firstTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0-001</td>
    <td>Computer</td>
    <td>$299.99</td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>

<table class="secondTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Customer ID</th>
    <th>Total Sales</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10001</td>
    <td>$39.94</td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.firstTable
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.firstTable td
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.firstTable th
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #00003f;
    color: #cfffff;
}
.secondTable
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.secondTable td
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.secondTable th
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #cfffff;
    color: #00003f;
}
```

And a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QW65m/)

*PS: `font-color` isn't a CSS attribute, it should be just `color`*

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the CSS3 [nth-of-type](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) selector.

CSS:

```
table:nth-of-type(odd) {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table:nth-of-type(odd) td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

This should allow you to select even and odd tables like the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nnvEr/)

Note that this won't work in older versions of IE (8 and below) but you should be able to work around that using https://stackoverflow.com/a/4742560/3387154

Answer (score 0):

would this not work?

```
.firstTable th td
{
border: 1px solid black;
}

.firstTable th
{
background: #00003f;
color: #cfffff;
}

.secondTable
{
border: 1px solid red;
}

.secondTable th
{
background: #cfffff;
color: #00003f;
}

.secondTable td
{
font-family: sans-serif;
}

<table class="firstTable">
<tr>
<th>Item</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Price</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>0-001</td>
<td>Computer</td>
<td>$299.99</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class="secondTable">
<tr>
<th>Customer ID</th>
<th>Total Sales</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10001</td>
<td>$39.94</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please explain what your fix does rather than just posting the fix. Looking at this I wouldn't know what you're suggesting.

Comment: The fix was in response to the original post. He explains what he's looking for.