# particular css is not coming on IE 8 onwards

Tags: css, internet-explorer, debugging

I have declared a style

```
.tableStyle2 tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #C5F0FC;
}
```

in my style sheet. but it is not reflecting on IE, works on FF and chrome. when I try to check in my debug in IE it is also not present but present for chrome and FF.

Any suggestion for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577674/how-to-make-internet-explorer-8-to-support-nth-child-css-element

Comment: As others have said, (IE8 and under) don't support CSS3. Either go the polyfill route with [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/), or apply classes to the even objects and apply the color to that, though, it's unclear whether that would be applicable in your application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742450/why-wont-my-alternating-css-table-row-styling-work-in-internet-explorer . It solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Older versions of IE don't allow for CSS3's nth-child selector. A work around would be to use jQuery to define a class on the nth-child and then style that class accordingly.

**jQuery**

```
$('#element li:nth-child(2n)').addClass('even');
```

**CSS**

```
#element li.even {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why not - `$('#element li:nth-child(even)').addClass('even');`

Comment: That'd work as well. Just blanked when I wrote that out. Same result, two less characters ;) Thanks for the edit as well. Makes it clearer.

Comment: No problem Robert, great answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectivizr. It's a very nice JS plugin which makes IE support css3 selector

http://selectivizr.com/